# Sorting a list while keeping its correspondence to another list

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have the following two lists:

```
ids = {5, 11, 17, 24, 31, 37, 40, 39, 38, 33, 32, 25}

values = {0.0351563, 0.131836, 0.086792, 0.0637894, 0.065752, 0.191388, 0.063796, 0.173784, 0.0503769, 0.0875244, 0.0146484, 0.0351563}
```

where entries in values correspond to entries in ids.

I now wish to sort ids in ascending order while maintaining the correspondence to values, such that elements in values must be changed according to the changes made to ids.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: `values[[Ordering@ids]]` and `SortBy[Transpose[{ids, values}], First] == 
 Transpose[{Sort@ids, values[[Ordering@ids]]}]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
With[{p = Ordering[ids]},
 idsnew = ids[[p]];
 valuesnew = values[[p]];
 ]
idsnew
valuesnew
```

> {5, 11, 17, 24, 25, 31, 32, 33, 37, 38, 39, 40}
>
> {0.0351563, 0.131836, 0.086792, 0.0637894, 0.0351563, 0.065752, 0.0146484, 0.0875244, 0.191388, 0.0503769, 0.173784, 0.063796}

Comment: This generates an error for me:
Set::write: Tag Times in valuesnew {5,11,17,24,25,31,32,33,37,38,39,40} is Protected.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a semicolon that was necessary after wrapping everything with `With`. Please try again.

Answer (score 6):

I would keep them together while sorting.

```
SortBy[Transpose[{ids, values}], First]
```

> ```
> {{5, 0.0351563}, {11, 0.131836}, {17, 0.086792}, {24, 0.0637894}, {25,
>    0.0351563}, {31, 0.065752}, {32, 0.0146484}, {33, 0.0875244}, {37, 
>   0.191388}, {38, 0.0503769}, {39, 0.173784}, {40, 0.063796}}
> ```

Comment: See also my remark under [Okke's post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/187168).

Answer (score 5):

```
AssociationThread[ids, values] // KeySort
```

**Edit**
To extract keys and values

```
sorted = AssociationThread[ids, values] // KeySort
sortedIds = Keys[sorted]
sortedValues = Values[sorted]
```

Comment: This looks simple, but how do I work with these afterwards?

Comment: @user120911 Added sorted key / value extraction.

Answer (score 3):

Since `Sort` sort it by the first entry by default

```
Sort@Transpose@{ids, values}
```

> {{5, 0.0351563}, {11, 0.131836}, {17, 0.086792}, {24, 0.0637894}, {25,
>      0.0351563}, {31, 0.065752}, {32, 0.0146484}, {33, 0.0875244}, {37, 
>     0.191388}, {38, 0.0503769}, {39, 0.173784}, {40, 0.063796}}

Comment: A problem that arises here with `Transpose` is is that it unpacks arrays: `ids` is a list of integers and `values` is a list of machine reals. So both can be packed separately; but not `Transpose@{ids, values}` as it has mixed data types. This  may become important when processing large datasets.